# File encoding isn't stable

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding, utf

I have a program that aims to detect the encoding of **big** files.
I'm trying to do so by sampling some data from the file (don't want to read all of it because of its size) and detecting the sample encoding, but I realize that it's not really stable..

For example I see this behavior on a `UTF-8` file:

1. reading first 2000 bytes: **UTF-8**
2. reading first 4000 bytes: **UTF-16**
3. reading first 8000 bytes: **UTF-8** again

Any explanation for this behavior?

Thanks!

[Edit]:

This is the relevant code:

```
private static final List<String> encodings = Arrays.asList(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16.name(), StandardCharsets.UTF_16LE.name(),StandardCharsets.UTF_16BE.name());

private String tryDecodeMultipleEncodings(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[BUFFER_LENGTH];
    inputStream.read(bytes);
    return tryDecodeMultipleEncodings(bytes);
}

private String tryDecodeMultipleEncodings(byte[] buffer) throws CharacterCodingException {
    for (String encoding : encodings) {
        if (tryDecode(buffer, encoding)) {
            return encoding;
        }
    }
    // LOG.warn("Failed decoding input, tried [" + String.join(", ", encodings) + "]");
    throw new CharacterCodingException();
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. It's hard to answer without knowing how you're "sampling" your file and what said file is. Please [edit] your question to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Do the files you're sampling contain a [Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#UTF-8) (BOM)?

Comment: Thanks @FedericoklezCulloca, I'll edit the question, by sampling I just mean reading X first bytes of the file

Comment: @OzZafar ok, but you still need to show us *how* you're reading your file and what (at least the beginning of) your file looks like, otherwise we can just throw guesses.

Comment: Deriving the encoding of a text file is not an exact science; it will pick the wrong encoding with a certain probability. By using sampling, the error probability will increase. So it is to be expected that different sample sets will result in different outcomes. You should probably ask a different question like: How can I improve my detection algorithm?

Comment: After thinking about it again, it should be rather reliable to tell UTF-8 and UTF-16 apart. (I's less reliable for other combinations.) Likely, your code can be improved. So please add it to the question. After all, you have tagged the question with "java".

Comment: For Unicode, encoding should be known (usually delivered out-of-the-band, or just protocol requirement). BOM could help (but it is really just for byte order, when you already know the encoding). Any character detection is a guess (and you can trigger wrong guesses).

Comment: @Codo added, thanks

Comment: Your approach for detecting the encoding is too simple to be useful (even after the bug have been fixed). First the bug: A codepoint takes several bytes to encode. So first you have to determine where a codepoint starts and end. If you start or end in the middle of codepoint, the decoding will fail even though the correct encoding was picked.

Comment: The main problem is that certain text files can be decoded without error for several encodings. So the result isn't unique. The resulting text will still be non-sense for most of them. You need decoder that returns a probability and then pick the encoding with the highest probability. There is no built-in class that does it.

Comment: Also note that since you only work with UTF-16 and UTF-8, there is a special case you can exploit: if the file starts with a byte order mark (BOM), the encoding can be determine unambiguously.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Codo